# Can't refresh JPanel while clicking button

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm new in java swing and I have a problem with refreshing my panel. 
Can you tell me why after clicking on button , the JTextField doesn't show in mainpanel?
Thanks in advance:)

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

    javax.swing.JTextField t = new javax.swing.JTextField("Hello");  
    mainPanel.add(t);      
    mainPanel.validate();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried repaint()? Also what layout are you using?

Comment: Try `invalidate`ing the `mainPanel` before `validate`ing it.

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Maybe using 'revalidate()' after that 'repaint()' helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling [revalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate%28%29) instead of validate()?

Answer (score 0):

You possibly forgot to set the layout of the `mainPanel`?

Try the following:

```
mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
mainPanel.add(new JTextField("Hello!"));
mainPanel.validate();
```

**UPDATE:**

The above suggestion was not clever enough.

As [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) pointed, `FlowLayout` is the default layout for `JPanel`.

The following suggestion will be more helpful, I hope.

Example, modelling the situation.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JPanelDefaultLayoutTest extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mainPanel;

    public JPanelDefaultLayoutTest () {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JPanelDefaultLayoutTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setTitle("Add hello.");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mainPanel = new JPanel();        

        JButton button = new JButton();   
        button.setText("Button");
        button.setToolTipText("Press me.");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JTextField hello = new JTextField("Hello!");
                mainPanel.add(hello);
                mainPanel.revalidate();
            }
        });

        setContentPane(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.add(button);
//        pack();
    // If you comment the next line (and uncomment the pack() method above),
    // you have to resize the frame manually,
    // to see the added hello after the button press.
        setSize(200, 75);
    }
}
```

**Conclusion:** if the size of your panel is too small, you have to resize it manually, to see the added JTextField instance.

Comment: You can't forget to set the layout because JPanel use a FlowLayout by default. However, it is possible the poster is trying to use a null layout which is not recommended and would cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my silly wild @ss guess: you're using NetBeans to build your GUI and the container that is supposed to accept the new JTextField, the mainPanel, uses NetBeans' GroupLayout, one that has a great deal of difficulty accommodating components added on the fly. If so, have mainPanel use a more user-friendly layout, or nest containers each using its own simple layout in order to achieve a complex GUI.

You'll want to read up on how to use these layout managers here: [Laying out Components in a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

You'll also want to provide enough information in this and your next questions so that we don't have to keep making SWAGs.